# How should one compare floats in OCaml?

Tags: floating-point, ocaml, comparison-operators

In OCaml, comparing Integer `0` with Integer `0` returns `true`;
however, comparing Float `0.` to Float `0.` returns `false`:

```ml
# 0 == 0;;
- : bool = true
# 0. == 0.;;
- : bool = false
```

How does one compare floats correctly?

Comment: always compare floats against a delta, for example if (f1 - f2) < 0.0000001

Comment: @Leo : you forgot the abs in the comparison.

Comment: you should use a relative comparison, instead of an absolute comparison generally.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama good point, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `==`, which is a specialized "physical equality". Use `=` for everyday code.

```
# 0 = 0;;
- : bool = true
# 0.0 = 0.0;;
- : bool = true
```

For inequality, use `<>`. The `!=` operator is for "physical inequality", which should also be avoided like the plague in everyday code.

```
# 0 <> 0;;
- : bool = false
# 0.0 <> 0.0;;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. But then how should we mitigate '!='?

    '# 0. != 0.;;
    - : bool = true
    # 0 != 0;;
    - : bool = false'

Comment: Excellent question. Use `<>`, for the same reason. I'll update my answer.